# Consuming encapsulated member event

Tags: c#

I'm trying to comsume an encapsulated member event. Let me explain. I have MyClassA, which has a private member of MyClassB _obj:

```
public class MyClassA
{
    private MyClassB _obj;
    public MyClassA()
    {
        _obj = new MyClassB();
    }
}
```

MyClassB has SaveProgress event.

For the client application, MyClassB is invisible. We need to handle its event through MyClassA:

```
public partical class _Default: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyClassA objA = new MyClassA();
        // We need to handle it's event through MyClassA
        // objA.SaveProgress += new EventHandler<SaveProgressEventArgs>(objA_SaveProgress);
    }
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If objA's SaveProgress event is only forwarded to an event of the MyClassB class, then you can use this:

```
public event EventHandler<SaveProgressEventArgs> SaveProgress
{
    add
    {
           lock(_obj.Event)
                _obj.Event += value;
    }
    remove
    {
           lock(_obj.Event)
           _obj.Event  -= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, that's what I want to know. thanks. but two modifications on this: 1) public event EventHandler<SaveProgressEventArgs>  SaveProgress; 2) lock(_obj.Event) gives error "The event can only appear in the left hand side of += or -=". So I removed them (any problems without lock?).

Comment: Thanks, I'll add the event type to the example.
It should be good without the lock.  I originally had it without the lock, but I checked msdn to make sure I had it right and it had me add the lock.  I forgot that the most current compiler won't let you lock events.